# How can I extract the first two characters of a string in shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, sh, gnu-coreutils

For example, given:

```
USCAGoleta9311734.5021-120.1287855805
```

I want to extract just:

```
US
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. 

I ended up using 'cut -c1-2', honestly I didn't even know 'cut' was there.

I'd like to say I'm pretty experienced at command line - but apparently I have a lot to learn.

Comment: @Greg, just be aware that cut is run as a separate process - it will be slower than the internal-bash solution I posted alongside it in my answer. That won't make any difference unless you're processing huge data sets but you need to keep it in mind.

Comment: [Edit] Actually, I think this line of code will probably be executed about 50,000 times per report. So I might just go with the internal Bash method - which as you said will save some much needed resources.

Answer (score 230):

Probably the most efficient method, if you're using the `bash` shell (and you appear to be, based on your comments), is to use the sub-string variant of parameter expansion:

```
pax> long="USCAGol.blah.blah.blah"
pax> short="${long:0:2}" ; echo "${short}"
US
```

This will set `short` to be the first two characters of `long`. If `long` is shorter than two characters, `short` will be identical to it.

This in-shell method is usually better if you're going to be doing it a lot (like 50,000 times per report as you mention) since there's no process creation overhead. All solutions which use external programs will suffer from that overhead.

If you also wanted to ensure a *minimum* length, you could pad it out before hand with something like:

```
pax> long="A"
pax> tmpstr="${long}.."
pax> short="${tmpstr:0:2}" ; echo "${short}"
A.
```

This would ensure that anything less than two characters in length was padded on the right with periods (or something else, just by changing the character used when creating `tmpstr`). It's not clear that you need this but I thought I'd put it in for completeness.

---

Having said that, there are any number of ways to do this with external programs (such as if you don't have `bash` available to you), some of which are:

```
short=$(echo "${long}" | cut -c1-2)
short=$(echo "${long}" | head -c2)
short=$(echo "${long}" | awk '{print substr ($0, 0, 2)}'
short=$(echo "${long}" | sed 's/^\(..\).*/\1/')
```

The first two (`cut` and `head`) are identical for a single-line string - they basically both just give you back the first two characters. They differ in that `cut` will give you the first two characters of each line and `head` will give you the first two characters of the entire input

The third one uses the `awk` sub-string function to extract the first two characters and the fourth uses `sed` capture groups (using `()` and `\1`) to capture the first two characters and replace the entire line with them. They're both similar to `cut` - they deliver the first two characters of each line in the input.

None of that matters if you are sure your input is a single line, they all have an identical effect.

Comment: I would rather use `printf '%s'` instead of `echo` in case there are weird chars in the string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40423558/895245 For the POSIX obsessed: `head -c` is not POSIX, `cut -c` and `awk substr` are, `sed \1` not sure.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心996ICU六四事件 using printf, you don't even need an additional program. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56585879/1054423).

Answer (score 79):

The easiest way is:

```
${string:position:length}
```

Where this extracts `$length` substring from `$string` at `$position`.

This is a Bash builtin, so awk or sed is not required.

Comment: This is the short, sweet and easiest way get the substring.

Comment: I would like to try this but it's missing key details on how it's run. Please add the entire command using the OP.

Answer (score 36):

You've gotten several good answers and I'd go with the Bash builtin myself, but since you asked about `sed` and `awk` and (*almost*) no one else offered solutions based on them, I offer you these:

```
echo "USCAGoleta9311734.5021-120.1287855805" | awk '{print substr($0,1,2)}'
```

and

```
echo "USCAGoleta9311734.5021-120.1287855805" | sed 's/\(^..\).*/\1/'
```

The `awk` one ought to be fairly obvious, but here's an explanation of the `sed` one:

- substitute "s/"
- the group "()" of two of any characters ".." starting at the beginning of the line "^" and followed by any character "." repeated zero or more times "*" (the backslashes are needed to escape some of the special characters)
- by "/" the contents of the first (and only, in this case) group  (here the backslash is a special escape referring to a matching sub-expression)
- done "/"

Comment: In awk strings start at index 1, so you should use `substr($0,1,2)`.

Comment: Interestingly, strings are both 0-indexed and 1-indexed (tested in Gawk 5.1.0 and MacOS awk 20070501). But it's better to use 1 for consistency with `index()`. Answer updated.

Answer (score 11):

Just grep:

```
echo 'abcdef' | grep -Po "^.."        # ab
```

Comment: Fits my needs. You can remove the `-P` option to make it shorter. All regexs will understand that pattern.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use shell scripting and not rely on non-posix extensions (such as so-called bashisms), you can use techniques that do not require forking external tools such as grep, sed, cut, awk, etc., which then make your script less efficient.  Maybe efficiency and posix portability is not important in your use case.  But in case it is (or just as a good habit), you can use the following *parameter expansion* option method to extract the first two characters of a shell variable:

```
$ sh -c 'var=abcde; echo "${var%${var#??}}"'
ab
```

This uses *"smallest prefix" parameter expansion* to remove the first two characters (this is the `${var#??}` part), then *"smallest suffix" parameter expansion* (the `${var%` part) to remove that all-but-the-first-two-characters string from the original value.

This method was previously described in this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/252406/273000) to the "Shell = Check if variable begins with #" question.  That answer also describes a couple similar parameter expansion methods that can be used in a slightly different context than the one that applies to the original question here.

Comment: Best answer, should be on top. no forks, no bashisms. works even with small shells such as dash.

Comment: I love to avoid bashism whenever possible.

Comment: Nice answer. It will be even better if the inner parameter expansion is quoted as `echo "${var%"${var#??}"}"`. (ref - https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2295 )

Answer (score 9):

If you're in `bash`, you can say:

```
bash-3.2$ var=abcd
bash-3.2$ echo ${var:0:2}
ab
```

This may be just what you need…

Comment: thes easiest and most simple answer! worked like a charm

Answer (score 8):

You can use `printf`:

```
$ original='USCAGoleta9311734.5021-120.1287855805'
$ printf '%-.2s' "$original"
US
```

Answer (score 6):

**colrm** — remove columns from a file

To leave first two chars, just remove columns starting from 3

```
cat file | colrm 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
sed 's/.//3g'
```

Or

```
awk NF=1 FPAT=..
```

Or

```
perl -pe '$_=unpack a2'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of fun Ill add a few that, although they are over complicated and useless, they were not mentioned :

```
head -c 2 <( echo 'USCAGoleta9311734.5021-120.1287855805')

echo 'USCAGoleta9311734.5021-120.1287855805' | dd bs=2 count=1 status=none

sed -e 's/^\(.\{2\}\).*/\1/;' <( echo 'USCAGoleta9311734.5021-120.1287855805')

cut -c 1-2 <( echo 'USCAGoleta9311734.5021-120.1287855805')

python -c "print(r'USCAGoleta9311734.5021-120.1287855805'[0:2])"

ruby -e 'puts "USCAGoleta9311734.5021-120.1287855805"[0..1]'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your system is using a different shell (not `bash`), but your system has `bash`, then you can still use the inherent string manipulation of `bash` by invoking `bash` with a variable:

```
strEcho='echo ${str:0:2}' # '${str:2}' if you want to skip the first two characters and keep the rest
bash -c "str=\"$strFull\";$strEcho;"
```

Comment: This uses the same method as [the main answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1405641/393280), only invoking `bash` if you aren't already using it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this comes with all of the overhead of invoking another process, but sometimes that overhead doesn't matter as much as simplicity and familiarity.

Answer (score 1):

**How to consider Unicode + UTF-8**

Let's do a quick test for those interested in Unicode characters rather than just bytes. Each character of `áéíóú` ([acute accented vowels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent)) is made up of two bytes in UTF-8. With:

```
printf 'áéíóú' | LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 awk '{print substr($0,1,3);exit}'
printf 'áéíóú' | LC_CTYPE=C awk '{print substr($0,1,3);exit}'
printf 'áéíóú' | LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 head -c3
echo
printf 'áéíóú' | LC_CTYPE=C head -c3
```

we get:

```
áéí
á
á
á
```

so we see that only `awk` + `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` considered the UTF-8 characters. The other approaches took only three bytes. We can confirm that with:

```
printf 'áéíóú' | LC_CTYPE=C head -c3 | hd
```

which gives:

```
00000000  c3 a1 c3                                          |...|
00000003
```

and the `c3` by itself is trash, and does not show up on the terminal, so we saw only `á`.

`awk` + `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` actually returns 6 bytes however.

We could also have equivalently tested with:

```
printf '\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa9\xc3\xad\xc3\xb3\xc3\xba' | LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 awk '{print substr($0,1,3);exit}'
```

and if you want a general parameter:

```
n=3
printf 'áéíóú' | LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 awk "{print substr(\$0,1,$n);exit}"
```

Question more specific about Unicode + UTF-8: https://superuser.com/questions/450303/unix-tool-to-output-first-n-characters-in-an-utf-8-encoded-file

Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/grabbing-the-first-x-characters-for-a-string-from-a-pipe

Tested on Ubuntu 21.04.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're after:

```
my $string = 'USCAGoleta9311734.5021-120.1287855805';

my $first_two_chars = substr $string, 0, 2;
```

Reference: [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html)

Comment: given that he/she is likely to be calling this from the shell, a better form would be `perl -e 'print substr $ARGV[0], 0, 2' 'USCAGoleta9311734.5021-120.1287855805'`

Answer (score -1):

The code

```
if mystring = USCAGoleta9311734.5021-120.1287855805

    print substr(mystring,0,2)
```

would print US.

Where 0 is the start position and 2 is how many characters to read.

Comment: Say...isn't that GW-BASIC? Oh, wait, that's `awk`. Sorry, I couldn't tell at first.

Answer (score -1):

```
perl -ple 's/^(..).*/$1/'
```

Comment: You forgot to echo the string into that.