# How can I check the first character in a string in Bash or Unix shell?

Tags: string, bash, unix, character, exitstatus

I'm writing a script in Unix where I have to check whether the first character in a string is "/" and if it is, branch.

For example, I have a string:

```
/some/directory/file
```

I want this to return 1, and:

```
server@10.200.200.20:/some/directory/file
```

to return 0.

Comment: [How to check if a string begins with some value in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2172352/608639).

Answer (score 188, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. You could use wildcards in double brackets:

```
str="/some/directory/file"
if [[ $str == /* ]]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
```

You can use substring expansion:

```
if [[ ${str:0:1} == "/" ]] ; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
```

Or a regex:

```
if [[ $str =~ ^/ ]]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi
```

Comment: To short, use: `${str::1}`.

Answer (score 20):

Consider the case statement as well which is compatible with most sh-based shells:

```
case $str in
/*)
    echo 1
    ;;
*)
    echo 0
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: I thought glob  `*` only matches a single path component, never across slashes `/`

Comment: The relevant POSIX quote is: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html "Case Conditional Construct" sentence "corresponding to the first one of several patterns (see Pattern Matching Notation)"

Comment: Also if you want to match a `#` you'll have to use quotes. For example: `'#'*) echo "found comment";;`.

Comment: I happen to have to write POSIX-compliant code (/bin/sh) thus @konsolebox's answer (although quite old) was most useful, thanks @konsolebox!

Answer (score 13):

```
$ foo="/some/directory/file"
$ [ ${foo:0:1} == "/" ] && echo 1 || echo 0
1
$ foo="server@10.200.200.20:/some/directory/file"
$ [ ${foo:0:1} == "/" ] && echo 1 || echo 0
0
```

Comment: Downvote! You forgot to quote your variable in single braces. ``foo='*'; [ ${foo:0:1} == "/" ] && echo 1 || echo 0`` is going to output this error ``bash: [: too many arguments``. Use ``[ "${foo:0:1}" == "/" ] && echo 1 || echo 0`` or even better ``[[ ${foo:0:1} == "/" ]] && echo 1 || echo 0``

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko-A. -  devnull's answer works without error in "GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc."

Comment: Your initial expression: "Downvote! You forgot to quote your variable in single braces." implies that the expressions entered in devnulls answer won't work as is on bash.  You need to modify that initial expression in order to properly deliver your technical point, otherwise it isn't logically correct.

Comment: @Mausy5043 it's not a “typo”, it is buggy and incorrect.

Answer (score 9):

**`printf '%c` "$s"**

This was mentioned by [brunoais](https://stackoverflow.com/users/551625/brunoais) in a comment, and it might be the best option since:

- it is likely [POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780599/what-is-the-meaning-of-posix). TODO confirm. The following quote from https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html suggests this:

  > It shall not be considered an error if an argument operand is not completely used for a b, c, or s conversion.
- it can extract the character to a variable unlike using `case` directly
- unlike `cut -c1` `printf` is a Bash built-in so it could be a little bit faster

```
myvar=abc
first_char="$(printf '%c' "$myvar")"
if [ "$first_char" = a ]; then
  echo 'starts with a'
else
  echo 'does not start with a'
fi
```

**`cut -c1`**

This is POSIX, and unlike [`case`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18489079/895245):

```
myvar=abc
first_char="$(printf '%s' "$myvar" | cut -c1)"
if [ "$first_char" = a ]; then
  echo 'starts with a'
else
  echo 'does not start with a'
fi
```

`awk substr` is another POSIX command, but less efficient alternative:

```
printf '%s' "$myvar" | awk '{print substr ($0, 0, 1)}'
```

`printf '%s'` is to avoid problems with escape characters: *[Bash printf literal verbatim string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423203/bash-printf-literal-verbatim-string/40423558#40423558)*, e.g.,

```
myvar='\n'
printf '%s' "$myvar" | cut -c1
```

outputs `\` as expected.

`${::}` does not seem to be POSIX.

See also: *[How can I extract the first two characters of a string in shell scripting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405611/extracting-first-two-characters-of-a-string-shell-scripting)*

Comment: Why the `printf`? Would that be because `echo` would remove spaces?

Comment: @AlexisWilke `echo` has implementation defined behaviour on escapes I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467424/echo-newline-in-bash-prints-literal-n/34947759#34947759

Comment: Specifically in the case of first char, you can use `first_char="$(printf '%c' "$myvar")"`

Answer (score 3):

Code:

```
 place="Place"
 fchar=${place:0:1}
 echo $fchar
```

Output:

```
P
```