# bash substring - combine command and slicing

Tags: bash, substring

I want to get first 8 characters of latest git commit hash. To retrieve git HEAD hash, I use `git rev-parse HEAD`. I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1405626/769384) that I can get a substring using `${string:position:length}`. But I don't know how to combine them both (in a one-liner, if possible). My attempt

```
${"`git rev-parse HEAD`":0:8}
```

is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot combine BASH substring directive by calling a command inside it:

Instead you can use:

```
head=$(git rev-parse HEAD | cut -c1-8)
```

Or else old faishon 2 steps:

```
head=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
head=${head:0:8}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
git rev-parse HEAD | sed 's/^\(.\{,8\}\).*$/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out=`git rev-parse HEAD`
sub=${out:0:8}

example:
a="hello"
b=${a:0:3}
bash-3.2$ echo $b
hel
```

its a two step process, where first the output of `git` command is extracted, which is a string. `${string:pos:len` will return the substring from pos of length `len`

Comment: its a two step process, where first the output of `git` command is extracted, which is a string. `${string:pos:len"` will return the substring from `pos` of length `len`