# Extract column using grep

Tags: unix, grep

I have a data frame with >100 columns each labeled with a unique string. Column 1 represents the index variable. I would like to use a basic UNIX command to extract the index column *(column 1) + a specific column string* using `grep`.

For example, if my data frame looks like the following:

```
Index  A  B  C...D  E  F
p1     1  7  4   2  5  6
p2     2  2  1   2  .  3
p3     3  3  1   5  6  1
```

I would like to use some command to extract only column "X" which I will specify with `grep`, and display both column 1 & the column I `grep`'d. I know that I can use `cut -f1 myfile` for the first bit, but need help with the `grep` per column. As a more concrete example, if my `grep` phrase were "B", I would like the output to be:

```
Index  B
p1     7
p2     2
p3     3
```

I am new to UNIX, and have not found much in similar examples. Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Take a look at awk.

Comment: You can make your question clearer by entering values like `p1a p1b p1c...p1f` in the second row.

Comment: Done! the values in columns (beside the header) are irrelevant to the search.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First figure out the command to find the column number.

```bash
columnname=C
sed -n "1 s/${columnname}.*//p" datafile | sed 's/[^\t*]//g' | wc -c
```

Once you know the number, use cut

```bash
cut -f1,3 < datafile
```

Combine into one command

```bash
cut -f1,$(sed -n "1 s/${columnname}.*//p" datafile | 
   sed 's/[^\t*]//g' | wc -c) < datafile
```

Finished? No, you should improve the first `sed` command when one header can be a substring of another header: include tabs in your match and put the tabs back in the replacement string.

Comment: Thank you so much. Having trouble with this command such that the first sed... outputs "1" no matter how I set my column name?

Comment: Did you set columnname to the name of one of the headers? When the part until the first pipe shows the header line without anything with the columnname taht past is working. Now look to the second `sed`. Are your fields seperated with tabs? When you have a variable number of spaces, it will be hard to recognise them between header fields with a space inside, like `this one` or `nr of errors`.

Answer (score 45):

You need to use awk:

```bash
awk '{print $1,$3}' <namefile>
```

This simple command allows printing the first ($1) and third ($3) column of the file. The software awk is actually much more powerful. I think you should have a look at the man page of awk.

A nice combo is using grep and awk with a pipe. The following code will print column 1 and 3 of only the lines of your file that contain 'p1':

```bash
grep 'p1' <namefile> | awk '{print $1,$3}'
```

If, instead, you want to select lines by line number you can replace grep with sed:

```bash
sed 1p <namefile> | awk '{print $1,$3}'
```

Actually, awk can be used alone in all the examples:

```bash
awk '/p1/{print $1,$3}' <namefile> # will print only lines containing p1
awk '{if(NR == 1){print $1,$3}}' <namefile> # Will print only first line
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. Can awk be used simply to return columns with grep when you do not know the column number but instead know the column name?

Comment: @Riccardo Petraglia: For you solution ```grep 'p1' <namefile> | awk '{print $1,$3}'``` what if I need only the first three characters of $3?

Comment: @anishjp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405611/how-to-extract-the-first-two-characters-of-a-string-in-shell-scripting

Comment: I think this is not addressing the question as OP wants to extract the column using the column name rather than the column position.

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia OP uses a hypothetical "column-wise grep" to explain what she/he wants to achieve. Despite the confusion, with the help of the example, OP makes the question imho clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the first column and a column which contains a specific string in the first row (eg. `B`), then this should work. It assumes that your string is only present once though.

```bash
awk '{if(NR==1){c=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){c++;if($i=="B"){n=c}}}; print $1,$n}' myfile.txt
```

There is probably a better solution with amazing awk, but this should work.

EXPLANATION: In the first row (NR==1), it iterates through all columns for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) until it finds the string, save the column number and then prints it.
If you want to pass the string as a variable then you can use the -v option.