# Ubuntu: How do I extract only specific columns from tab-delimited file if it contains a specific string?

Tags: ubuntu, awk, grep

I want to extract lines with `chr6.fa` from the FC305JN_s_1_eland_result.txt file. Then, I want to extract only columns 1, 2, 7, 8, and 9 from this sub-file.

```
grep -E "chr6.fa" FC305JN_s_1_eland_result.txt > out.txt
awk -F, '{OFS=",";print $1, $2, $7, $8, $9}' out.txt > outfile.txt
My out.txt is exactly the same as outfile.txt.
```

Small sample of the `FC305JN_s_1_eland_result.txt` file:

```
>FC305JN_20080525:1:15:1412:166 GTGAATCCTTATTCCGATATATATNNNN    U0  1   0   0   chrX.fa 45974622    R   ..
>FC305JN_20080525:1:15:944:72   GATGACTTCCTTAATTTTCTTTATNNNN    U0  1   0   0   chr6.fa 7200804 R   ..
>FC305JN_20080525:1:15:1049:473 GAATGGCAACACAAACAGGGCTGANNNN    R2  0   0   4
>FC305JN_20080525:1:15:1196:1959    GGGAGAAGCCTCCCCGCCTCGGCCNNNN    U2  0   0   1   chr17.fa    38386704    F   ..  17A 23T
>FC305JN_20080525:1:15:1034:505 GAAAATGTTTCAAATCAATTTCTANNNN    U0  1   0   0   chr2.fa 183305566   R   ..
>FC305JN_20080525:1:15:983:126  GGATAGAGAGTTTGCACTGAGTTGNNNN    U0  1   0   0   chrX.fa 92367529    F   ..
>FC305JN_20080525:1:15:1799:100 TTCAGCTTATTGATAAAGAAGCACNNNN    U0  1   0   0   chr6.fa 20979453    R   ..
>FC305JN_20080525:1:15:743:1028 GAATGGAATGGAATGGAAAGAAACNNNN    R1  0   33  255
>FC305JN_20080525:1:15:771:1076 GAGTTCACTAAACAAAAGAGTGTCNNNN    U2  0   0   1   chr6.fa 136877852   R   ..  7A  13G
```

Current output outfile.txt (Example):

```
>FC305JN_20080525:1:15:944:72   GATGACTTCCTTAATTTTCTTTATNNNN    U0  1   0   0   chr6.fa 7200804 R   ..
>FC305JN_20080525:1:15:1799:100 TTCAGCTTATTGATAAAGAAGCACNNNN    U0  1   0   0   chr6.fa 20979453    R   ..
>FC305JN_20080525:1:15:771:1076 GAGTTCACTAAACAAAAGAGTGTCNNNN    U2  0   0   1   chr6.fa 136877852   R   ..  7A  13G
```

Desired output (Example):

```
>FC305JN_20080525:1:15:944:72   GATGACTTCCTTAATTTTCTTTATNNNN    chr6.fa 7200804 R
>FC305JN_20080525:1:15:1799:100 TTCAGCTTATTGATAAAGAAGCACNNNN    chr6.fa 20979453    R
>FC305JN_20080525:1:15:771:1076 GAGTTCACTAAACAAAAGAGTGTCNNNN    chr6.fa 136877852   R
```

Comment: _tab-delimited file_ is not `-F,`. Try `-F"\t"` instead. Consider that for `OFS` as well.

Comment: @JamesBrown still the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifying your code (with code borrowed from [Extract column using grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551560/extract-column-using-grep))

```
grep -E "chr6.fa" FC305JN_s_1_eland_result.txt > out.txt
awk '{print $1, "\t", $2, "\t", $7, "\t", $8, "\t", $9}' out.txt > outfile.txt
```

**produces output:**

```
FC305JN_20080525:1:15:944:72     GATGACTTCCTTAATTTTCTTTATNNNN    chr6.fa     7200804     R
FC305JN_20080525:1:15:1799:100   TTCAGCTTATTGATAAAGAAGCACNNNN    chr6.fa     20979453    R
FC305JN_20080525:1:15:771:1076   GAGTTCACTAAACAAAAGAGTGTCNNNN    chr6.fa     136877852   R
```

Comment: This is close to what I want. But how do I maintain the output as a tab-delimited file? Thanks

Comment: Change awk line to  ---->.   awk '{print $7, "\t", $2, "\t", $1, "\t", $8, "\t", $9}' out.txt > outfile.txt

Comment: Why does the order look so strange?

Comment: You mean `awk '{print $1, "\t", $2, "\t", $7, "\t", $8, "\t", $9}' out.txt > outfile.txt`

Comment: Sorry order change was just to make verification that grepped value was in return set for each row.  First column is easier to visually scan.  FIXED in answer

Answer (score 2):

In full awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"               # set correct delimiters
}
$7~/chr6\.fa/ {               # replaces the grep part
    print $1, $2, $7, $8, $9  # output
}'  file                      # your file goes here
```

Output:

```
>FC305JN_20080525:1:15:944:72   GATGACTTCCTTAATTTTCTTTATNNNN    chr6.fa 7200804 R
>FC305JN_20080525:1:15:1799:100 TTCAGCTTATTGATAAAGAAGCACNNNN    chr6.fa 20979453        R
>FC305JN_20080525:1:15:771:1076 GAGTTCACTAAACAAAAGAGTGTCNNNN    chr6.fa 136877852       R
```