# Bash printf literal verbatim string

Tags: bash, unix, printf, bsd, verbatim

To make my code portable, I try to use `printf` rather than `echo`. But then

```
printf "-dogs-cats"
```

returns an error. A workaround in the present case is:

```
printf "-";printf "dogs-cats"
```

But is there a general, portable command (or an option with `printf`) that will print an arbitrary string as a literal/verbatim, not try to interpret the string as a format?

I work in [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) Unix (on a Mac), but my objective is code that would work in other Unix flavors as well.

Answer (score 11):

Use a format specification:

```
printf '%s' "-dogs-cats"
```

Comment: I like this answer best as it is applicable to crazy control sequences that one might want to use without the shell interpreting them.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `--` after `printf` to let it know that no more arguments are to come and to consider the string as so:

```
$ printf -- "-dogs-cats" 
-dogs-cats                    # no new line after this
```

This is a *NIX-trick that can be used for many other commands. As [Bash Reference Manual → 4 Shell Builtin Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) says:

> Unless otherwise noted, **each builtin command documented** as accepting options preceded by ‘-’ **accepts ‘--’ to signify the end of the options**. The :, true, false, and test builtins do not accept options and do not treat ‘--’ specially. The exit, logout, return, break, continue, let, and shift builtins accept and process arguments beginning with ‘-’ without requiring ‘--’. Other builtins that accept arguments but are not specified as accepting options interpret arguments beginning with ‘-’ as invalid options and require ‘--’ to prevent this interpretation.

---

Note why this happens:

```
$ printf "-dogs-cats" 
bash: printf: -d: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

This makes `printf` understand the first part of the string, `-d`, as an argument.

Comment: was about to post this as answer :D probably also point out that printf doesn't add newline by default

Comment: Alternately, use a format specification: `printf "%s" "-dogs-cats"`

Comment: This doesn't work in all cases - try doing `printf -- "/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"` - you would get `I': invalid format character`. I used a combination of your answer and @chepner answer with %s and that worked.